# Solving differential equation in perturbation theory

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, perturbation-theory, differential-equations, anharmonic-oscillators

The differential equation of an anharmonic Oscillator with Newtonian friction is
$$ 
\ddot{x}+\varepsilon \dot{x}^2+x=0
.$$
The initial conditions of the System are
$$
\begin{align*}
x(0)&=1\\
\dot{x}(0)&=1
.\end{align*}
$$
The System can be approximated with perturbation theory to the first order, so
$$
x=x_0+\varepsilon x_1
.$$
Plugging this into the differential equation and comparing the coefficients leads to
$$
\begin{align*}
\ddot{x}_0+x_0&=0\\
\ddot{x}_1+x_1&=-\dot{x}_0^2
.\end{align*}
$$
The new initial conditions are
$$
\begin{align*}
x_0(0)&=1\\
\dot{x}_0(0)&=0\\
x_1(0)&=0\\
\dot{x}_1(0)&=0
.\end{align*}
$$
All this leads to the solution for $x_0$ and $x_1$
$$
\begin{align*}
x_0(t)&=\cos (t)\\
x_1(t)&=-\dfrac{1}{3}\left(\cos (t)-1\right)^2
.\end{align*}
$$

**Question:** How is the differential equation for $x_1(t)$ solved?

**Attempt:** I can solve the equation for $x_0(t)$. My attempt for $x_1(t)$ was to split it into the homogeneous and inhomogeneous part and add them together in the end. I can solve the homogeneous part, but not the inhomogeneous part. I tried an approach with the variation of constants, but it doesn't seem to work. The problem could be that variation of constants only works with first order differential equation, but that is just a guess.

**Note:** I'm citing the German Wikipedia on perturbation theory https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B6rungstheorie_(klassische_Physik). It is the first example.

Comment: hint: $\cos^2 t =(1+\cos2t)/2$

Comment: With this hint, transform the equation to Laplace domain you obtain x(s) from here back to time domain thus x(t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want  to solve this ODE

$$\ddot x+x=-\sin^2(t)=-\frac 12\,(1-\cos(2t))$$

with the initial conditions $~x(0)=0~,\dot x(0)=0~$

transfer it to Laplace domain ,obtain the  partial fraction and transfer each fraction back to time domain, this is the solution $~x(t)~$

$$X(s)\,(s^2+1)=-\frac {2}{s\,(s^2+4)}\quad\Rightarrow$$
$$X(s)=-\frac{1}{s^2+1}\frac {2}{s\,(s^2+4)}=\underbrace{-\frac{1}{2s}}_{-\frac 13}+\underbrace{\frac 23\frac{s}{s^2+1}}_{+\frac 23\cos(t)}
\underbrace{-\frac 16\frac{s}{s^2+4}}_{-\frac 13\,\cos^2(t)}$$

$$x(t)=-\frac 13+\frac 23\cos(t)-\frac 13\cos^2(t)=-\frac 13(\cos(t)-1)^2$$